# Splitting up the digits in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to learn regex in python. I came across the "split" function where we have to give pattern and the string. I could understand the below output:

```
a = '123456789'
b = re.split("(4)", a)
print(b)
['123', '4', '56789']
```

But I could not understand this below output. Why is "3" is not printing out in the output? Can someone please explain?

```
a = '123456789'
b = re.split("\d(4)", a)
print(b)
['12', '4', '56789']
```

Comment: `\d` consumed it.

Comment: This is not a typo. It's about understanding what the "typo" does.

Comment: if the capture group surrounded _both_ `(\d4)` the `34` would be an element. Anything _not_ captured is considered a boundary and removed. Like split("34567") would give `['12','89']` and `split("\d+")` is likely `['']` Thats really all there is to know, nothing complicated. There are some boundary _bias conditions that should be stated in the docs. Study/understand that.

Comment: Using regex with _split_ can get extremely complex though. Most switch to findall when they hit the wall.

Answer (score -1):

You have told it to split at `\d(4)`, so it will find a part of your string that matches `\d(4)`. That part is `34`, `3` for `\d` and `4` for `(4)`.

If you split the string there, you get `12` in front of it and `56789` after it.

For the middle part, you have only put the `4` into a capturing group: `(4)`, so only the `4` will be captured, not the `3`.

Things to try next for a better understanding:

- use `\d4` as the delimiter, without any capturing group
- use `(\d4)` as the delimiter, including the 3 in the capturing group

Solutions available at https://ideone.com/3yCKGF